# Transfer function of complex circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, power-electronics, transfer-function

I am trying to find the transfer function of this circuit, but I am confused about the modeling of the 1:1 transformer. How do I derive the transfer function of this circuit? Vout/Vab = ?

[image]

Comment: You need to ask a question about what you want to know.

Comment: What are you confused about specifically?

Comment: "Trying to find" means you have actually tried something -- can you show that? Otherwise it will be impossible for anyone to show you where exactly you went wrong and how to correct it. Also, are there input and output resistances?

Comment: When you say a transfer function, you have to tell what is the stimulus and what is the response. I assume the stimulus is the left-side ac source while the response is \$V_{out}\$ collected across \$R_1\$? If you neglect the magnetizing inductance of the right-side transformer, this is a 3rd-order circuit. If you bring \$L_{mag}\$ in, then it becomes a 4th-order and complicates the analysis. Anyway, the transformer must be replaced by an equivalent model featuring the leakage inductance and a simple turns ratio - which makes it a 4th-order circuit anyway : {

Comment: I am not sure, but I have seen such a circuit several years ago under the keyword "lossless feedback".

Comment: Have you components values? Because of different behavior choices ...

Answer (score 3):

The difficulty here is to analyze a circuit featuring two coupled inductors affected by a coupling coefficient. The best is to replace it by an equivalent circuit where you have a leakage inductance and a magnetizing inductance, all computed with the coupling coefficient. This is what I illustrated below with the original circuit and its equivalent:

[image]

The transfer function is that of a resonating band-pass filter (with my arbitrarily-selected values) and magnitude/phase graphs from the original circuit and the equivalent one are identical. You would now analyze this equivalent circuit for determining the transfer function symbolically.

Unfortunately, you have a 4th-order (\$L_8\$ and \$L_f\$ are in series) circuit you must solve. I would of course shoot for the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs described in my [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371) on the subject. As an example, you can have a look at the example I documented [here](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Divers/5th%20order.zip). It is not an insurmountable exercise but it requires care and patience to get there.

Comment: Thank you, it is very difficult for me. But I will try to figure it out using your approach. Actually, transformer is tricky for me, I thought that it can be modelled with depended source.

Comment: I agree this is complicated and a tough exercise considering the 4th-order network. What is the purpose of this circuit and where does it take place?

Comment: It is for the inverter output part. Also, I did not see any transformer reduction approach in your book. Should I need to use dependent source?

Comment: Yes, you can use dependent sources, this is what the transformer subcircuit hosts. As an advice, simulate the entire non-simplified circuit and record the ac response. Then go for simplifications step-by-step and compare responses at each step of the simplification process with the original one. Any deviation indicates either a mistake or a bad simplification. If all is well, the final circuit on which you carry the analysis should have the exact same response of the original one.

Comment: After solving some exercises, I obtain transfer function for 5th circuit. But I will share it with you, there is no 1:1 transformer yet. I will try to pass one step further. I want to ask one more question about it. If I change 1:1 transformer with depended voltage source, can I apply your methods that circuit, it will include extra one more input source. Sometimes it will be short or stays same. Is it possible to proceed same steps as you described in your book. [(link to circuit)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJdoe.png)

Comment: @ivanmateo - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it was really a follow-up question to an answer. Therefore I converted it into the comment above. (a) Please do not abuse answers in that way. (b) If you did that in order to include images, use [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) technique. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image & is then discarded. (c) An answer's author doesn't have to answer follow-up questions in comments. In fact a *substantial* new question should be asked separately. This looks borderline to me.